# Is there a way to pass a set of Include() calls as a parameter

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have all users in my system split between 2 tables in 2 databases. Yes I know this is not great, but we have an Identity database that has the user's login as well as email, phone, etc. I use that database but don't get to change its schema.

Then I have my database. It has a user table too with a ton of properties for each user. These share a property, the IdentityUser.Id value. And it's on me to keep them in sync as needed.

I have a class that has a DbContext to both databases and it performs actions on them together, to keep them in sync. It all works well except for defining the includes for my user record. At present I have:

```
public async Task<CombinedUser?> FindAsync(int userId, params string[] includes)
{

    Trap.Break();
    IQueryable<AppUser> query = AppDbContext.AppUsers;
    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);
    query = query.Where(u => u.Id == userId);
    var user = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (user == null)
        return null;

    var identityUser = await IdentityDbContext.Users.FindAsync(user.IdentityUsersId);
    if (identityUser == null)
        return null;

    return new CombinedUser(identityUser, user);
}
```

And this works fine. But I'd prefer to be able to pass in a set on `Include().Include().Include()` instead of the `string[] includes`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method signature:

```
public async Task<CombinedUser?> FindAsync(int userId, params Expression<Func<AppUser, object>>[] includes)
```

The method body does not change.

Call:

```
var user = await FindAsync(id, x => x.Foo, x => x.Bars);
```